# If $f$ has mean zero then $f'$ also has mean zero?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Let $f:[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable function.

**Question.** If
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;dx=0,$$
then
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx=0?$$

I thought this:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;dx=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}0=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;dx= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\;dx=\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx \ $$
And therefore
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx=0$$

That's true?

Comment: How about $f(x) = x$ from $-1 to 1$

Comment: Note that in $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x) dx$ you are accidentally trying to differentiate w.r.t. a bound variable!

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $f(x)=x$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. The average value of the function is $0$, but the derivative is constant,  $f'(x)=1$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Take $f(x)=x,$ $a=-1 , b=1$.

Comment: It seems to me that if $ f: [0, L] \subset \mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is periodic,  $\int_{0}^{L} f(x)\;dx=0$ and with a period $ L> 0 $, then $\int_{0}^{L} f'(x)\;dx=0$. Right?

Comment: Yes, since $$\int_0^L f'(t) dt = f(L) - f(0) =0$$